# When adding a child Node to a TreeView in c# it visually looks wrong

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add a child node to a TreeView in a WinForms app (using C#). 
The problem is when I use the following code the winform looks wrong visually. Here's my example:

```
if (treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            TreeNode newGuy = new TreeNode("New_SubItem");
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(newGuy);
            newGuy.BeginEdit();
            return;
        }

        TreeNode n = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        TreeNode n3 = new TreeNode("New_SubItem");

        n.Nodes.Add(n3);
        n3.BeginEdit();
        return;
```

Here is what happens:
[image: inserting a node into TreeView]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but what OS are you running this on?

Comment: if (treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0) then treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes will throw an exception, are you able to run it?

Comment: Also, how does `treeView1.Nodes[0]` not throw an exception if you only get to that code when `treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0`?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, because if there are no nodes, I'm adding the root.

Comment: I failed to answer your question: I'm running on OS Windows 8.1

Comment: Oh, my TreeView automatically comes with a root node. That's why it's not throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. You use the Insert method rather than the add method:

```
//n.Nodes.Add(n3);
n.Nodes.Insert(treeView1.SelectedNode.Index, "New_SubItem");
```

Comment: I forgot to include the MSDN article I found: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w99w164(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just FYI, `n.Nodes.Insert(treeView1.SelectedNode.Index, "New_SubItem");`
in your case does the same thing as writing `n.Nodes[0].Add("New_subitem")`;

Answer (score 0):

```
if (treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        TreeNode newGuy = new TreeNode("New_SubItem");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(newGuy);
        newGuy.BeginEdit();
        return;
    }
```

That code is senseless: first you check that treeView1 has no nodes(treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0), then you try to access first node it it's correct(treeView1.Nodes[0])

Comment: If there are no nodes, then I'm just adding a root node.

Comment: but think how can you add to Node[0], if you made sure before that there is no such node?

Comment: What max is saying is that your condition states that if the node count is 0, then access node[0].. Node 0 is a node.  So if you were able to access node[0], then the node count would be 1.  [0] is an index, not a count..  The node at index 0 would be a node, so it's just wrong... is your condition supposed to be if (treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count == 0)?

Comment: Oh, my TreeView comes with a root node.

Comment: If it has a root node, then the treeView1.Nodes.Count would never = 0.. It would always be 1 or more.  So I don't see how it would ever hit this logic...

Comment: @maxpovver Thank you for violating Stack Overflow's admonitions to treat other people with respect. "That code is senseless:"

Answer (score 0):

Edited.  Per comment in a different solution, her Treeview has a root node...

In that case, this change should work.

```
if (treeView1.Nodes.Count == 0)
```

change to

```
if (treeView1.Nodes.Count == 1)
```

Comment: I'm not using the Nodes[0].Count, I'm simply determining if the Nodes collection contains any nodes. If the Count is zero, (Nodes.Count) it doesn't contain any nodes, therefore I instantiate a new TreeViewNode and add it on to the collection.

Comment: Oh, I see your point, inside the if statement I'm accessing Nodes[0]. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Yes.  I added the extra check to show the difference.  Nodes[0] is a node, so if nodes.count = 0, then nodes[0] would be wrong.  You don't need the second "if" statement, I just wanted to show the difference.  Once you add the root node, you can access Nodes[0] without error.

Comment: I edited the answer per your comment in a different answer that said you always have a root node.  Basically, you're not hitting your first if statement, I believe that is probably causing the issue with the rest of the code.